# Wordpress passing data as parameter to page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a page with a google maps streetview.

```
[streetview width="100%" height="250px" lat="34.360988" lng="-86.693436" heading="-94.17771883289124" pitch="-3.342175066312998" zoom="1"][/streetview]
```

My page need to display 20-30 different street view pages, i want to reuse the same page and pass thr lat/lng as parameters when going to the page, so i dont have to make 20-30 pages.

What's the best way to pass the data when going to the page?

Comment: I think you need to create 20-30 pages.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is to make a custom post type (lets call it LordStreetview), and just have the add/edit form have text inputs for the lat and lng.

Then in your theme you can have a single-LordStreetview.php for your custom post type to render a single street view, and a archive-LordStreetview.php for displaying a bunch.

see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates and https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: With regards to the archive view: be aware that you can feasibly hit the [Google Maps usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro#usage_limits) if you do this: you're limited to 50 requests per minute. We had this issue with a store locator that displayed 90+ stores. Our work around was lazy loading; only making the GM request once the store had been scrolled into view. If you're on shared hosting you might also end up hitting the limit, as you can end up with multiple sites using the same IP. Had this issue on another site, and had to change hosts!